# ControlValueAccessor.writeValue() called multiple times when using FormControl.setValue()

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

Consider following reactive form setup:

Lets have custom `SimpleInputComponent` that implements `ControlValueAccessor` interface. Add it to the the app template wrapped with `ngIf` directive, so we can re-invoke the `SimpleInputComponent`'s lifecycle when the `ngIf` expression changes.

As the `SimpleInputComponent` is bound to `FormControl` instance with `formControlName` directive, you can change it's value by calling `FormControl.setValue` method.

I expect the `FormControl.setValue` to trigger `SimpleInputComponent.writeValue` exactly once. Unfortunately that is not true.

The `FormControl.setValue` calls `SimpleInputComponent.writeValue` as many times as many times the `SimpleInputComponent`'s lifecycle is invoked.

Now to simulate the problem you need at least 2 components:

SimpleInputComponent:

```js
import { Component, forwardRef, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR, ControlValueAccessor, FormControlName } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'simple-input-text',
  template: `
    <input [name]="formControlName" type="text" 
      [(ngModel)]="value"
      (input)="onChange($event)"
      (blur)="onBlur()" />
  `,
  providers: [
    { provide: NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR, useExisting: forwardRef(() => SimpleInputComponent), multi: true }
  ]
})
export class SimpleInputComponent implements ControlValueAccessor {
  private value: string;

  constructor() { }

  propagateChange: any = () => {};
  propagateTouch: any = () => {};

  onBlur() {
    this.propagateTouch();
  }
  onChange(event) {
    this.propagateChange(event.target.value);
  }

  writeValue(value: any): void {
    console.log('writeValue() called');
    this.value = value;
  }
  registerOnChange(fn: any): void {
    this.propagateChange = fn;
  }
  registerOnTouched(fn: () => void): void {
    this.propagateTouch = fn;
  }
  setDisabledState?(isDisabled: boolean): void {}
}
```

AppComponent:

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup, FormControl } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <div>
      <button (click)="hidden = !hidden">{{hidden ? 'show' : 'hide'}}</button>
      <button (click)="changeValue()">change value</button>
    </div>

    <div [formGroup] = "form" *ngIf="!hidden">
      <simple-input-text formControlName="test"></simple-input-text>
    </div>
  `
})
export class AppComponent  {
  hidden = false;

  form = new FormGroup({
    test: new FormControl('')
  });

  changeValue(): void {
    console.log('changeValue() called');
    this.form.get('test').setValue('another value');
  }
}
```

The `AppComponent` contains 2 buttons:

1. show/hide - to re-invoke the `SimpleInputComponent`s lifecycle
2. change value - to run `FormControl.setValue` updating `SimpleInputComponent` by implementing own `writeValue` method

Simulation scenario:

- click "show/hide" button (2n) times
- open a console click the "change value" button
- check the console and see that writeValue is called (n + 1) times (1 is from initial lifecycle)

Live sample is at https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bgp3kg

So the question is: Am i doing something wrong?

Comment: It looks like a known issue. See https://github.com/angular/angular/pull/22503

Answer (score 0):

I see the PR for this fix is still open. You can check it out here. https://github.com/angular/angular/pull/29335.

Mean while for a work around, you can define ngOnDestroy inside SimpleInputComponent as below,

```
ngOnDestroy() {
    if (this.ngControl) {
      this.ngControl.reset();
      this.ngControl.valueAccessor &&
        (this.ngControl.valueAccessor.writeValue = () => {});
    }
  }
```